# C++Builder - IAutoComplete implementation causes crash when the Form is closed if Bind called

Tags: c++builder

If found this class implementation on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2371/IAutoComplete-and-custom-IEnumString-implementatio) which I adapted to C++Builder.  While it works it will crash when the form is closed if I had called `Bind()` function.   If I don't release the object and let it leak resources there is also no crash.

Here is the class (note: have not tested registry stuff, not planning on using it):

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           CCustomAutoComplete (CCUSTOMAUTOCOMPLETE.H)
//  Type:           Wrapper class
//  Description:    Matches IAutoComplete, IEnumString and the registry (optional) to provide
//                  custom auto-complete functionality for EDIT controls - including those in
//                  combo boxes - in WTL projects.
//
//  Author:         Klaus H. Probst [kprobst@vbbox.com]
//  URL:            http://www.vbbox.com/
//  Copyright:      This work is copyright © 2002, Klaus H. Probst
//  Usage:          You may use this code as you see fit, provided that you assume all
//                  responsibilities for doing so.
//  Distribution:   Distribute freely as long as you maintain this notice as part of the
//                  file header.
//
//
//  Updates:
//
//
//  Notes:
//
//
//  Dependencies:
//
//                  The usual ATL/WTL headers for a normal EXE, plus <atlmisc.h>
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#if !defined(CCustomAutoComplete_INCLUDED)
#define CCustomAutoComplete_INCLUDED

#if _MSC_VER >= 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER >= 1000

#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Registry.hpp>
#include <string.h>

// Bring in the GUID hack and the shell stuff
#include <initguid.h>
#include <shldisp.h>
#include <shlguid.h>

class CCustomAutoComplete : public IEnumString
{

private:

    TStringList *m_pasList;
    IAutoComplete *m_pac;
    TRegistry* m_reg;

    ULONG m_nCurrentElement;
    ULONG m_nRefCount;
    BOOL m_fBound;


public:


    // Constructors/destructors

    CCustomAutoComplete()
    {
        InternalInit();

    }

    CCustomAutoComplete(const HKEY p_hRootKey, const String& p_sSubKey)
    {
        InternalInit();

        SetStorageSubkey(p_hRootKey, p_sSubKey);

    }

    CCustomAutoComplete(TStringList* p_sItemList)
    {
        InternalInit();

        SetList(p_sItemList);
    }


    ~CCustomAutoComplete()
    {
        if (m_reg)
            delete m_reg;

        if (m_pac)
            m_pac->Release();

        if (m_pasList)
            delete m_pasList;
    }

    BOOL ListExists(bool create=false)
    {
        if (m_pasList)
            return TRUE;

        if (!create)
            return FALSE;

        return SetList(NULL);
    }

public:

    // Implementation

    BOOL SetList(TStringList* p_sItemList)
    {
        Clear();

        if (m_pasList)
            delete m_pasList;

        try {
            m_pasList=new TStringList;
            if (p_sItemList) {
                m_pasList->Assign(p_sItemList);
            }
        }
        catch(...) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    BOOL SetStorageSubkey(LPCTSTR p_lpszSubKey, HKEY p_hRootKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    {
        return SetStorageSubkey(p_hRootKey, String(p_lpszSubKey));
    }

    BOOL SetStorageSubkey(HKEY p_hRootKey, const String& p_sSubKey)
    {
        assert(p_hRootKey);
        assert(p_sSubKey.Length());

        if (InitStorage(p_hRootKey, p_sSubKey))
            return LoadFromStorage();

        return FALSE;
    }

    BOOL Bind(HWND p_hWndEdit, DWORD p_dwOptions = 0, LPCTSTR p_lpszFormatString = NULL)
    {
        assert(::IsWindow(p_hWndEdit));

        if ((m_fBound) || (m_pac))
            return FALSE;


        HRESULT hr = S_OK;

        if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AutoComplete, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IAutoComplete, (void**)&m_pac))) {
            if (p_dwOptions) {
                IAutoComplete2 *pac2;
                if (SUCCEEDED(m_pac->QueryInterface(IID_IAutoComplete2, (void**)&pac2))) {
                    hr = pac2->SetOptions(p_dwOptions);
                    pac2->Release();
                }
            }

            hr = m_pac->Init(p_hWndEdit, this, NULL, p_lpszFormatString);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                m_fBound = TRUE;
                return TRUE;
            }

            m_pac->Release();
            m_pac=NULL;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    VOID Unbind()
    {
        if (!m_fBound)
            return;

        assert(m_pac);

        if (m_pac) {
            m_pac->Release();
            m_pac=NULL;
            m_fBound = FALSE;
        }
    }

    BOOL AddItem(String& p_sItem)
    {
        if (ListExists(true)) {
            if (p_sItem.Length() != 0) {
                if (m_pasList->IndexOf(p_sItem) == -1) {
                    m_pasList->Add(p_sItem);

                    if (m_reg)
                        return AddToStorage(p_sItem);

                        return TRUE;
                }
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    BOOL AddItem(LPCTSTR p_lpszItem)
    {
        String s=p_lpszItem;
        return AddItem(s);
    }

    INT GetItemCount()
    {
        if (m_pasList) {
            return m_pasList->Count;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    BOOL SetRecentItem(const String& p_sItem)
    {

        // Only supported if registry persistance is enabled.
        // Call this function after setting the registry root
        if ((!m_reg) || (!m_fBound))
            return FALSE;


        return WriteRecentItem(p_sItem);
    }

    BOOL GetRecentItem(String& p_sItem)
    {
        // Only supported if registry persistance is enabled.
        // Call this function after setting the registry root
        if ((!m_reg) || (!m_fBound))
            return FALSE;

        return ReadRecentItem(p_sItem);
    }

    BOOL RemoveItem(String& p_sItem)
    {
        if (m_pasList && p_sItem.Length() != 0) {
            int i;
            if ((i=m_pasList->IndexOf(p_sItem)) != -1) {
                m_pasList->Delete(i);
                if (m_reg)
                    return RemoveFromStorage(p_sItem);
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    BOOL RemoveItem(LPCTSTR p_lpszItem)
    {
        String s=p_lpszItem;
        return RemoveItem(s);
    }


    BOOL Clear()
    {
        if (m_pasList && m_pasList->Count != 0) {
            if (m_reg) {
                if (!ClearStorage())
                    return FALSE;
            }

            m_pasList->Clear();

            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    BOOL Disable()
    {
        if ((!m_pac) || (!m_fBound))
            return FALSE;

        return SUCCEEDED(EnDisable(FALSE));

    }

    BOOL Enable(VOID)
    {

        if ((!m_pac) || (m_fBound))
            return FALSE;

        return SUCCEEDED(EnDisable(TRUE));

    }

public:

    //
    //  IUnknown implementation
    //
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef()
    {
        return ::InterlockedIncrement(reinterpret_cast<LONG*>(&m_nRefCount));
    }

    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release()
    {
        ULONG nCount = 0;
        nCount = (ULONG) ::InterlockedDecrement(reinterpret_cast<LONG*>(&m_nRefCount));

        if (nCount == 0)
            delete this;

        return nCount;

    }

    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject)
    {

        HRESULT hr = E_NOINTERFACE;

        if (ppvObject != NULL)
        {
            *ppvObject = NULL;

            if (IID_IUnknown == riid)
                *ppvObject = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);

            if (IID_IEnumString == riid)
                *ppvObject = static_cast<IEnumString*>(this);

            if (*ppvObject != NULL)
            {
                hr = S_OK;
                ((LPUNKNOWN)*ppvObject)->AddRef();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            hr = E_POINTER;
        }

        return hr;

    }

public:

    //
    //  IEnumString implementation
    //
    STDMETHODIMP Next(ULONG celt, LPOLESTR* rgelt, ULONG* pceltFetched)
    {

        HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;

        if (!celt)
            celt = 1;

        ULONG i;
        for (i = 0; i < celt; i++)
        {

            if (m_nCurrentElement >= GetItemCount())
                break;

            rgelt[i] = (LPWSTR)::CoTaskMemAlloc((ULONG) sizeof(WCHAR) * (m_pasList->Strings[m_nCurrentElement].Length() + 1));
            wcscpy(rgelt[i], m_pasList->Strings[m_nCurrentElement].c_str());

            if (pceltFetched)
                (*pceltFetched)++;

            m_nCurrentElement++;
        }

        if (i == celt)
            hr = S_OK;

        return hr;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP Skip(ULONG celt)
    {

        m_nCurrentElement += celt;

        if (m_nCurrentElement > GetItemCount())
            m_nCurrentElement = 0;

        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP Reset(void)
    {

        m_nCurrentElement = 0;
        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP Clone(IEnumString** ppenum)
    {

        if (!ppenum)
            return E_POINTER;

        try {
            CCustomAutoComplete* pnew = new CCustomAutoComplete();

            if (m_pasList) {
                pnew->SetList(m_pasList);
            }
            pnew->AddRef();
            *ppenum = pnew;

            return S_OK;
        }
        catch(...) { };
        return S_FALSE;

    }

private:

    // Internal implementation

    void InternalInit()
    {
        m_pac=NULL;
        m_nCurrentElement = 0;
        m_nRefCount = 0;
        m_fBound = FALSE;
        m_reg = NULL;
        m_pasList = NULL;
    }

    HRESULT EnDisable(BOOL p_fEnable)
    {

        HRESULT hr = S_OK;

        assert(m_pac);

        hr = m_pac->Enable(p_fEnable);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            m_fBound = p_fEnable;

        return hr;


    }

    BOOL InitStorage(HKEY p_hRootKey, const String& p_sSubKey)
    {
        if (m_reg)
        {
            delete m_reg;
            m_reg=NULL;
        }

        m_reg = new TRegistry(KEY_READ|KEY_WRITE);
        if (m_reg) {
            if (m_reg->OpenKey(p_sSubKey, true)) {
                return TRUE;
            }
            delete m_reg;
            m_reg=NULL;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }


    BOOL RemoveFromStorage(const String& p_sItem)
    {
        assert(m_reg);

        BOOL result=FALSE;
        try {
            result=m_reg->DeleteValue(p_sItem);
        }
        catch(...) { };

        return result;
    }


    BOOL LoadFromStorage()
    {
        assert(m_reg);

        if (GetItemCount() != 0)
            m_pasList->Clear();

        BOOL result=TRUE;

        try {
            TStringList *values=new TStringList;
            m_reg->GetValueNames(values);

            for (UINT i=0;i<values->Count;i++) {
                try {
                    String s=m_reg->ReadString(values->Strings[i]);
                    if (!s.IsEmpty()) {
                        if (!m_pasList->Add(s)) {
                            result=FALSE;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(...) {
                    result=FALSE;
                };
            }

            delete values;
        }
        catch (...) {
            result=FALSE;
        }

        return result;
    }

    BOOL ClearStorage()
    {

        // Since we do not hold the parent key to our
        // own HKEY, we need to iterate through the
        // array and delete each one.

        if (m_pasList) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m_pasList->Count; i++)
            {
                if (!RemoveFromStorage(m_pasList->Strings[i]))
                    return FALSE;
            }
        }

        return TRUE;

    }


    BOOL AddToStorage(const String& p_sName)
    {

        assert(m_reg);

        try {
            m_reg->WriteString(p_sName, p_sName);
            return TRUE;
        }
        catch(...) {};

        return FALSE;
    }


    BOOL WriteRecentItem(const String& p_sItem)
    {
        assert(m_reg);

        try {
            m_reg->WriteString(_D("_Recent"), p_sItem);
            return TRUE;
        }
        catch(...) {};

        return FALSE;
    }

    BOOL ReadRecentItem(String& p_sItem)
    {

        assert(m_reg);

        try {
            p_sItem=m_reg->ReadString(_D("_Recent"));
            return TRUE;
        }
        catch (...) {};

        return FALSE;
    }
};

#endif // !defined(CCustomAutoComplete_INCLUDED)
```

This is how I use it:

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    try {
        m_pAutoComplete=new CCustomAutoComplete();
        m_pAutoComplete->Bind(ButtonedEdit1->Handle, ACO_AUTOSUGGEST);

        TStringList* sl=new TStringList;
        sl->Add(_D("Test@xyz.com"));
        sl->Add(_D("Tester@yahoo.com"));
        sl->Add(_D("darpa@hotmail.com"));

        m_pAutoComplete->SetList(sl);
        delete sl;
    }
    catch(...) { };
}


void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Note: I tried putting this in the ~TForm1 destructor as well.
    if (m_pAutoComplete) {
        if (m_pAutoComplete->Release()) {
            m_pAutoComplete=NULL;
        }
    }

}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Remy's answer change the `FormDestory()` as follows to ensure object is released:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (m_pAutoComplete) {
        m_pAutoComplete->Unbind();
        m_pAutoComplete->Release();
        m_pAutoComplete=NULL;
    }
}
```

Also be a good idea to move the destructor to be `private` to ensure `Release()` must be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are holding a reference to the `CCustomAutoComplete` object in your `m_pAutoComplete` variable, but you are not incrementing the object's reference count, so it is still at its initial value of 0 when `Bind()` is called.

Then, `Bind()` passes `this` to `m_pac->Init()`, which will increment the `CCustomAutoComplete` object's reference count to 1, but there are really 2 references to it.

Then later on, when things are being cleaned up, the reference count of the `CCustomAutoComplete` object ends up falling to 0 prematurely, destroying the object, while your `m_pAutoComplete` variable is still referring to the object.  Your code then crashes when you try to `Release()` the object.

To fix this, you need to call the object's `AddRef()` method after you assign the object reference to your `m_pAutoComplete` variable, eg:

```
m_pAutoComplete = new CCustomAutoComplete();
m_pAutoComplete->AddRef(); // <-- ADD THIS!
...
```

`AddRef()` and `Release()` need to be balanced!  `AddRef` increments the reference count, and `Release()` decrements it.

A better option is to stop using raw interface pointers and manual reference counting in the first place.  Use a smart interface wrapper class instead that handles those details for you, such as `CComPtr`, `TComInterface`, `DelphiInterface`, etc.

Comment: Before I left I had tried setting the `m_nRefCount` to default to 1 instead of 0.  But even though I called `Release()` there was a memory leak (using deleaker) that none of the string lists and IIRC the other objects as well.   I'll try again adding the ref after the new and then release and see if it still leaks..

Comment: I tried it, same result, the destructor is not called. It gets a reference on the Bind() call but that reference isn't released? IAutoComplete::Init() results in QueryInterface() for the object which sets a ref to itself, that reference is not released. I will just call Unbind as well which should take care of it...